# Spring boot return a response from callback in services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am trying to develop sample Rest API application using Spring boot to test my java client library (Which is a conversion of a JS Client). Java client does some async tasks and returns response as callback.

Here is example of how i am calling it from my sample application's service.

```
@Async
public void initializeUser(InitRequest initRequest) {

    String BASE_URL = "http://sample_url";

    client.initUser(BASE_URL, initRequest, new ResponseCallback<InitRequest>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull InitRequest arg0) {
            // Return arg0 to controller
            System.out.println("User Initialized: " + arg0.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull ResponseBody error) { 
            // Return error to controller
            System.out.println("User Initialize failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void validationError(@NonNull String arg0) {
             // return validationError to controller
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

Here initUser is method implemented in my client. When i call this method from my controller. controller returns before actual request is finished and i am not able to see any response in postman.

Here is a controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/init" )
public void initUser( @RequestBody InitRequest initRequest) {
    experimentServices.initializeUser(initRequest);
    // wait for request to finish and send response to user
}
```

Like in javascript i can use promises or async/await to wait till the services gives response before returning to user.

I wanted to know.....

1) How to achieve something similar in Java? (Services returns some data to controller which then goes as a response to end user).

2) Java methods needs specific return response while services might gives Error, ValidationError or Successfull response object. Is there a way to properly handle all this in a single function?

Any links or documentation will help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code , the method that you are calling asynchronously is a void method, meaning it won't return anything.In Spring, annotating a method of a bean with `@Async` will make it execute in a separate thread i.e. the caller will not wait for the completion of the called method.

So , if you want the controller to wait till the execution is completed, If you want to wait for the result I suggest you use `Future`. You could take the approach where you wrap the actual return in the `Future` instance.I haven't tried compiling this code , but something like below :

```
@Async
public Future<T> initializeUser(InitRequest initRequest) {

    String BASE_URL = "http://sample_url";

    client.initUser(BASE_URL, initRequest, new ResponseCallback<InitRequest>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull InitRequest arg0) {
            return new AsyncResult<InitRequest>(arg0);
            System.out.println("User Initialized: " + arg0.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull ResponseBody error) { 
            return new AsyncResult<ResponseBody>(error);
            System.out.println("User Initialize failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void validationError(@NonNull String arg0) {
             return new AsyncResult<String>(arg0);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

and in the rest controller to receive this :

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/init" )
public InitRequest initUser( @RequestBody InitRequest initRequest) {
  Future<T> futureResult = experimentServices.initializeUser(initRequest);
  // wait for request to finish and send response to user
  if (futureResult.isDone()) {
      return futureResult.get();
  }
}
```

Comment: Any link for sample on how to use Future? i saw Something like FutureComplete .

Comment: For this to work i will have to change JAVA client method  `public void onSuccess`  to return Future instance instead of void right?

Comment: @DhavalP If you are returning void , it means you are not returning any results to the controller. If you want the controller to wait for a result then you should change it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is to avoid busy waiting on server, so use DeferredResult:

```
private ExecutorService executor = ....

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/init" )
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<InitResponse>> initUser(@RequestBody InitRequest initRequest) {
    final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<InitResponse>> output = new DeferredResult<>(5000L, 5000L);
    executor.submit(() -> {
        InitResponse response = processAndcreateRespnse(...);
        output.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK));
    });

    return output;
}
```